# DropDownList in Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, .net, drop-down-menu, visible

I put Two dropdownlist in my aspx page. second one is visible false. 
When I select some item from first DropDownList, I visible the second DropDownList. 
But, My Problem is when I Visible the second DropDownList, it will take me on the top of the page.  so, everytime I need to scroll page down to reach dropdownlist control..

I want to when I visible the Second DropDownList, I will make sure do not go to the top of the page.

Help me out?

Comment: Can you show us what have you tried so far ?

Comment: Do you have updatepanel in your page. if not use updatepanel

Answer (score 1):

Remember that adding `MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true"` is only half the battle won. And without a proper Browser capabilities file in `App_Browsers` folder, your postback will not work correctly.

Here is my Chrome.browser file I use on all projects:

```
<!--
    You can find existing browser definitions at
    <windir>\Microsoft.NET\Framework\<ver>\CONFIG\Browsers
-->
<browsers>
    <browser id="NewBrowser" parentID="Mozilla">
        <identification>
            <userAgent match="Unique User Agent Regular Expression" />
        </identification>

        <capture>
            <userAgent match="NewBrowser (?'version'\d+\.\d+)" />
        </capture>

        <capabilities>
            <capability name="browser" value="My New Browser" />
            <capability name="version" value="${version}" />
          <capability name="supportsMaintainScrollPositionOnPostback" value="true"/>
        </capabilities>
    </browser>

    <browser refID="Mozilla">
        <capabilities>
            <capability name="xml" value="true" />
            <capability name="supportsMaintainScrollPositionOnPostback" value="true"/>
        </capabilities>
    </browser>
  <browser refID="Safari1Plus">
    <capabilities>
      <capability name="supportsMaintainScrollPositionOnPostback" value="true"/>
    </capabilities>
  </browser>
</browsers>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution `MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback` you can use it as follows

```
    <%@ Page MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true" %>
```

Here is a good link

[MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback property doesn't works with mozilla](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9607139/maintainscrollpositiononpostback-property-doesnt-works-with-mozilla)

 http://weblogs.asp.net/hosamkamel/archive/2007/09/07/maintain-scroll-position-after-postbacks-in-asp-net-2-0.aspx

Edit 1:-

**But I will suggest you to use java-script for hiding the second drop-down list.**
It will not create a round-trip to the server only for showing and hiding the drop-down list.

Answer (score 0):

Make `MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true"`