# Maintain scroll position when using Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I would like to maintain my scroll position when using:

```
Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl)
```

The reason for this is because I have a button in my GridView that updates a value in the Grid.  After clicking the button I want to update the value in the Gridview, which needs `Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl)` but I also want to maintain the scroll position.

This does not work either:

```
maintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true"
```

I have tried other Javacript methods and they do not work as well, since I am refreshing the page.

How would I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback property doesn't works with mozilla](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9607139/maintainscrollpositiononpostback-property-doesnt-works-with-mozilla)

Comment: This has nothing to do with that post.  Were talking about two different things.

Comment: no need to call `Response.Redirect`, Bind gridview after update and enjoy

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it.

I replaced `Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl)` with `GridView1.DataBind()`